# Column Does not belong to table ? C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve value directly from data table and inserting into a new database table.
I have to get values from more than one table. So I have used `INNER JOIN Query` to get value from `multiple table`. The values are getting on `data table "dt"`. Now I want to insert those values into my `new table.` But while using the given below code showing one error. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank You.

Code:

```
 MailTableAdapters.tbl_MailTableAdapter EM;
 EM = new MailTableAdapters.tbl_MailTableAdapter();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = EM.GetEmpMail();

 foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
      string SiteName = r["Site_Name"].ToString();
      string SiteID = r["Site_ID"].ToString();
      string AssingnedTeam = r["Assingned_Team"].ToString();
      string AssignedList = r["Assigned_List"].ToString();
      string EmpID = r["Emp_ID"].ToString();
      string EmpName = r["Employee_Name"].ToString();
      string EMail = r["Email"].ToString();
    }
```

SQL:

```
SELECT Site_Name, Site_ID, Assigned_Team, Assign_List, Emp_ID, Employee_Name, Email FROM  tbl_AutoAssignCadTeam INNER JOIN tbl_MailTable ON tbl_MailTable.Team = tbl_Employee.Team INNER JOIN tbl_Emp ON tbl_EmployeeToTeam.Emp_ID = tbl_Emp.Emp_ID
```

Comment: "C# 8"!? Current version is 5, next (Roslyn) is 6: so what is "8"?

Comment: A simple step through of the code would have shown your typo (you also spelt Assigned_Team wrong)  - probably would have been quicker than posting a question to SO!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you select `Assign_List` from the database, but use `Assigned_List` in your code. `Assigned_List` is not in the columns selected from the database.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that spelling mistake. Now it is working Perfectly.

Comment: @Torsten: yeah, sure.